# CMake configuration returns FOREACH Invalid integer Error

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to compiler [this legacy code](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/elmerfem/tree/wip/mac) but when running `cmake ..` in the build folder, I get the error:

```
CMake Error at fem/tests/CMakeLists.txt:17 (FOREACH):
  FOREACH Invalid integer: 'depth'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  fem/tests/CMakeLists.txt:29 (SUBDIRLIST)
```

referring to this CMake macro:

```
MACRO(SUBDIRLIST result curdir depth)
  set(glob_pattern "*")
  FOREACH(D RANGE 1 depth)
    FILE(GLOB children RELATIVE ${curdir} ${glob_pattern}) 
    FOREACH(child ${children})
      IF(IS_DIRECTORY ${curdir}/${child})
        LIST(APPEND dirlist ${child})
      ENDIF()
    ENDFOREACH()
    set(glob_pattern "${glob_pattern}/*")
  ENDFOREACH()
  SET(${result} ${dirlist})
ENDMACRO()
```

in [this file](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/elmerfem/blob/wip/mac/fem/tests/CMakeLists.txt), and I was not able to find anything similar to this on the internet. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

My environment is:

- CMake 3.17.0
- macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
  FOREACH(D RANGE 1 depth)
```

Should be:

```
  FOREACH(D RANGE 1 ${depth})
```

`depth` is a variable name, so in this context, it should be referenced using `${depth}`.